# Can't install Aptana Studio 3 on Windows

Tags: aptana3

I have just downloaded the Windows setup file from release 3.7.2.201807301111 for Aptana Studio 3. It failed to install with the following error message:

Failed to correctly acquire installer_git_windows.exe file: CRC error.

I tried a second time and got the same error. I am running Windows 10 with the latest updates on a 64 bit system. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem solved by installing the Git from http://go.appcelerator.com/installer_git_windows.exe. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you give me a little bit of background to where you found that installer and how I could navigate to it myself? When I click the link, I'm immediately prompted to download the exe file. I'm a bit reluctant to do that without having a clearer idea of where it came from.